# User Authentication and Authorization using Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring, session, authentication, spring-roo

I'm new to Spring Roo and would like to know how to implement user authentication and authorization. I followed the tutorial and focused on Spring Security but it doesn't really do what I want. I'd like to present the user with a login page where they enter their email and password. The email and password will then be compared to a 'User' table in MySQL and if it exists, present the user with a different user interface depending on the 'role' attribute in the table (e.g, a doctor user has a different user interface and a patient user has a different interface). What would be the proper steps to doing this?

I can connect to MySQL fine, I'm just not sure how to go about creating the login page and creating some kind of active session.

Comment: Which tutorial do you used. -- I think it would be help full to know what you already know, so the answer must not repeat everything.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html
In particular, section 2.10

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 8 in this [book](http://www.manning.com/rimple/) (highly recommended!) goes into some detail how to set up spring security using a database in spring roo.  Reading that chapter will also show you how to customize the UI based on the role.  Alternatively, this [blog](http://roosbertl.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/using-spring-security-database-in.html) gives some pointers in setting up a database for credentials with roo.

If you want more than just customizing the UI based on the role, for example, if you want to redirect users based on their role to different parts of the site after login, then this [link](http://oajamfibia.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/role-based-login-redirect/#comment-12) presents two options.